# Trying to implement held key binds

Tags: java, key-bindings

I am trying to build a game similar to Jetpack joyride, in which the user can hold down space to go up, and let go to go down. I have a test version of gravity working well enough but am still trying to figure out how to test to see if spacebar is held. My idea is that when the spacebar is held, it can set `spaceHeld` to true, and when it is not pressed, set it to false. here is my code:

````
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Calendar;



public class Game {
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel player;

    boolean grounded = false;
    int velocity = 0;
    int finalY = 0;
    boolean spaceHeld = false;


    Action spaceAction;

    Game() {
         
        frame = new JFrame("Nicholas Seow-Xi Crouse");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        player = new JLabel();
        player.setBackground(Color.red);
        player.setBounds(10, 1800, 50, 50);
        player.setOpaque(true);

        spaceAction = new SpaceAction();

        player.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "spaceAction");
        player.getActionMap().put("spaceAction", spaceAction);

        frame.add(player);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
         Timer flightTime = new Timer();
         TimerTask flight = new TimerTask() {
         
            public void run() {
                  if(velocity > -5) {
                  velocity -= 1;
                  }
                  else{
                  velocity = -5;
                  }
                  if (finalY < -61) {
                   finalY = finalY + velocity;
                   }
                   else{
                   finalY = -61;
                   }
                   player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + finalY);
                   if (player.getY() <= 0){
                   cancel();
                   velocity = 0;
                   finalY = 0;
                   player.setLocation(player.getX(), 0);
                    
                   }  
            }
      };
         

         Timer gravityTime = new Timer();
         TimerTask gravity = new TimerTask() {


            //creates a timer run method that simulates the falling gravity when not grounded
            public void run() {
                if(velocity < 5){
                velocity += 1;
                }
                else{
                velocity = 5;
                }
                //creates the variable the tells where the player is located
                if (finalY < 61) {
                finalY = finalY + velocity;
                }
                else{
                finalY = 61;
                }
                player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + finalY);
                if (player.getY() >= 1000){
                cancel();
                velocity = 0;
                finalY = 0;
                player.setLocation(player.getX(), 990); 
                }
                
            }
        };

        if (grounded == false && spaceHeld == false ) {
            gravityTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(gravity, 0, 33);
        }
        if (grounded == false && spaceHeld == true ) {
            flightTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(flight, 0 ,33);
    }
}

   //Creates the SpaceAction method that recieves input from the keyboard and moves the player downward
    public class SpaceAction extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            spaceHeld = true;
            //creates the grounded variable the tells the computer whether or not the player is on the ground
            
            }

} 
} ```

the spaceHeld boolean is used to see if space is held to change values, while the grounded boolean tells the program that the user is on the ground. Help is appreciated!
````

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: You can use key down and key up events to know when the button is pushed down and when it releases again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when the `space` key is being held, you should use two events.

1. On `keyPressed` set your held `boolean` to `true`
2. on `keyReleased` set your held `boolean` to `false`

Here is a small example:

```java
AtomicBoolean spaceHeld = new AtomicBoolean(false);

KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(ke ->
{
    switch (ke.getID())
    {
        case KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED:
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            {
                spaceHeld.set(true);
            }
            break;

        case KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED:
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            {
                spaceHeld.set(false);
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
});
```